# Discord - Get server info

Tags: javascript, discord

im using discord api to get infos from some server that my bot isnt

API: https://discord.com/api/v6/

i've already tried [https://discord.com/api/v6/guild/{id-here}](https://discord.com/api/v6/guild/%7Bid-here%7D), bcuz i can get invite infos using [https://discord.com/api/v6/invite/{invite-code}](https://discord.com/api/v6/invite/%7Binvite-code%7D)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get information from a server your bot is not in. Don't try to use the API natively if you're a beginner. Use a wrapper like Discord.js.